# Java/SpotBugs, What is a "named static inner class", if it's being declared in an interface?

Tags: java, static-analysis, lint, findbugs, spotbugs

I inherited a codebase that uses MyBatis. SpotBugs is telling me that that `SubjectRepositoryQueries` `could be refactored into a named _static_ inner class.` I've never encountered this term, I was hoping someone could explain what exactly it's asking me to do better. It would seem that `SubjectRepositoryQueries` is in fact named (it's not anonymous), and it's already static. `SubjectRepositoryQueries` can't be declared private because it's inside an interface.

```
@Mapper
public interface SubjectRepositoryService {
  @SelectProvider(type = SubjectRepositoryQueries.class, method = "search")
  List<Subject> search(SubjectSearch subjectSearch);

  static final class SubjectRepositoryQueries {
    public String search(final SubjectSearch subjectSearch) {
      ... some string generation
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `static` is superfluous as any `class` declared in an `interface` is `public static` by default.

Comment: "inner class" by the JLS definition can't be declared with `static`. So it seems like they misused the term

Comment: try to add the class SubjectRepositoryQueries into static inner class @JonathanS.Fisher

Comment: @Andrew that's why this is confusing

Comment: @Mohammad can you answer with a code example? I'm not sure I follow

Comment: I've added why I thought of this answer

Comment: @Michael that's a good point actually... Java8+ supports that

Comment: @Michael if you'll post that as an answer, I'll accept that so you get the SO credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear what the specific warning means. If your only goal is to remove the warning then given that your inner class isn't implementing an interface, you can simply convert it to a static method.

```
@Mapper
public interface SubjectRepositoryService {
    //...

    static String search(final SubjectSearch subjectSearch) {
        //... some string generation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you declare an inner class

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {
    }
}
```

even when you haven't declared any fields in Inner, the java compiler will automatically insert a synthetic field that holds the outer class reference, typically called something like this$0. So if you run javap on the Inner class, you will see it.

The idea is, that in many cases, having that reference variable is a waste of space, and more importantly causes things like serialization to cause unexpected problems.

Imagine that the outer class had all kinds of fields in it, and was massive. Now imagine you wanted to only serialize the inner class, if you tried that you would be surprised to find that the entire inner and outer instance would be serialized making for a much slower and bigger experience.

By decorating the inner class with 'static' you are removing this synthetic field reference to the outer class, and stopping that from happening.

There are other things that having a normal inner class causes. For instance you can't create an instance of the inner class without creating the outer class, which causes really arcane syntax like

```
Outer.Inner i = new Outer().new Inner();
```